Dark artifacts appering in render when using subsurface shading on joined meshes
I have this dark artifacts on parts of the meshes when they intersect each other, the parts are just joined, not boolean together, this happens when I use subsurface effect in my shading properties of material. When I use boolean, it disappears. Is there a way to avoid having those dark spots, without welding the mesh together with boolean?
Cheers,
Piotrek




The problem is gone after using boolean, but i would like not to use it

Set the subsurface scattering method from Random Walk to Christensen-Burley. This will get rid of the dark shadows but might require tweaking the settings, because it changes the overall look of the subsurface scattering as well. Or you switch to Blender 4.x where they have reworked the Principled BSDF node and the problem is no longer existent or at least less prominent.

Oh, anoying black subsurf artifacts are definitely here in 4.2
